# searching for the node within the singly-linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have the singly linked list consisting of nodes with the following structure:

```
struct date
{
    int day, month, year;       
};
struct Node
{
    string item;
    date Exp;
    int count;
    Node *link;
};
typedef Node* NodePtr;
```

When I search for the expiration date, all the other nodes show up when I search for it, but not the first node. This happens when I change the order of the nodes too. Is it a simple mistake?

Here's the function that I use for searching for the node:

```
NodePtr search_date(NodePtr head, int month, int day, int year)
{
    // Point to the head node
    NodePtr here = head;

    // If the list is empty nothing to search
    if (here == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Search for the item    
    else{
        //while you have still items and you haven't found the target yet 
        while (here-> Exp.day != day && 
               here-> Exp.month != month && 
               here->Exp.year != year &&
               here->link != NULL) 
            here = here->link; 

        // Found the target, return the pointer at that location 
        if (here-> Exp.month == month &&
            here-> Exp.day == day &&
            here-> Exp.year == year) 
            return here;

        // Search unsuccessful, return Null 
        else 
            return NULL; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to narrow the problem down to a *minimal* sample of code that displays the problem.

Comment: why don't you include the code directly instead of linking to it?

Comment: @didierc: I considered moving it into the question, but it's quite a bit longer than is really "comfortable" for a message.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y172mYiE

Comment: @JerryCoffin I understand. Hopefully OP will come up with a shorter version which can be "inlined".

Comment: Those are the specifics. Thanks!

Comment: OP, please, if you have a shorter version, just include it _directly_ instead of linking to it.

Comment: @KevinMurphy: When you're shortening the program for inclusion, you need to remove the parts that aren't really relevant to your question, but still leave enough that what you have left demonstrates the problem -- e.g., I should be able to compile and run it, and see what problem you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the condition within your `while` statement. Let's say that you are looking for the date `03/21/2013` and the first item that you will "examine" will have the date `04/21/2013`. Days are not equal, thus the condition will be evaluated as `false` and even if there is a record with the date you are looking for, you'll never reach it.

This function could look like this:

```
NodePtr search_date(NodePtr node, int month, int day, int year)
{    
    // while there is some node still:
    while (node)
    {
        // if we found the right node, return it:
        if (node->Exp.month == month &&
            node->Exp.day == day &&
            node->Exp.year == year) 
            return node;

        // move to the next node:
        node = node->link;
    }

    // we haven't found it:
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@LiHO is basically right : your comparison logic is flawed.

A good way of fixing this is to make a comparison operator for `date`

```
struct date
{
    int day, month, year;

    bool operator==(const date &lhs, const date &rhs)
    {
      return (rhs.day == lhs.day) && (rhs.month == lhs.month) (rhs.year == lhs.year);
    }
};
```

Then your loop simplifies down to

```
NodePtr search_date(NodePtr head, const date &wantedDate)
{
  for (NodePtr p == head; p != NULL; p = p->link)
    if (p.Exp == wantedDate)
     return p;

  return NULL;
}
```

Warning. untested ;-)

Comment: +1 I was thinking about something like this too. Just note that the data member of `Node` that he's looking for is called `Exp` as expiration date. It should be `if (p.Exp == wantedDate)`